# Unable to resolve .local domains with getent even though avahi-resolve-host-name succeeds

Tags: cups, mdns, avahi

Trying to set up a network printer with CUPS.

Followed online documentation that stated:

> To discover or share printers using DNS-SD/mDNS, setup .local hostname
> resolution with Avahi and restart cups.service.

Followed directions for setting up Avahi to the point where `avahi-browse --all --ignore-local --resolve --terminate` and `avahi-resolve-host-name my-domain.local` are both working.

But `getent hosts my-domain.local` fails to resolve. This results in CUPS failing to print because it can't find my-printer.local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read the mdns Github page and saw a note that made me think I didn't need a `/etc/mdns.allow` file.

> nss-mdns has a simple configuration file /etc/mdns.allow for enabling
> name lookups via mDNS in other domains than .local.
>
> Note: The "minimal" version of nss-mdns does not read /etc/mdns.allow under any circumstances. It behaves as if the file
> does not exist.
>
> In the recommended configuration, no /etc/mdns.allow file is present.

But then I saw the last note in that section:

> If, during a request, the system-configured unicast DNS (specified in
> /etc/resolv.conf) reports an SOA record for the top-level local name,
> the request is rejected. Example: host -t SOA local returns something
> other than Host local not found: 3(NXDOMAIN). This is the unicast SOA
> heuristic.

I tested that out on my machine and sure enough, I was getting something OTHER than `Host local not found...`.

Adding a `/etc/mdns.allow` file with a line for `.local.` and for `.local` and now I can ping `my-printer.local`.